# Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:

Tags: android, onresume

I'm having this error everytime I try to interact with the application. I don't know what should I write to the onResume method.

```
    package hu.frontrider.space;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import hu.frontrider.space.Helper.OrientationUtils;


public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static Button start_button;
    private static Button exit_button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        StartButtonClick();
        OrientationUtils.lockOrientationPortrait(MainMenu.this);

    }
    public void StartButtonClick()
    {
        start_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.StartButton);

        start_button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent game = new Intent("hu.frontrider.space.GameActivity");
                        startActivity(game);

                    }

                }

        );


    }

    public void ExitButonClick()
    {

        exit_button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                }
        );
    }



}
```

The error log. It seems that The thread on the called activity (not even the freezing one) if I try to do any interaction, the thread triggers a few times then the entire thing freezes.If i don't touch anything nothing happens. I haveN't touched this activity in a while.

```
08-29 12:46:45.345  11566-11566/hu.frontrider.space E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {hu.frontrider.space/hu.frontrider.space.MainMenu}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {hu.frontrider.space/hu.frontrider.space.MainMenu}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3492)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3579)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:179)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-29 12:46:46.575  11566-11566/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ec3eb8
08-29 12:46:46.645  11566-11566/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ec91d0
08-29 12:46:46.725  11566-11566/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ed12c0
08-29 12:54:42.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-29 12:54:42.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 410: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-29 12:54:42.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-29 12:54:42.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-29 12:54:42.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 432: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-29 12:54:42.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-29 12:54:42.755  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-29 12:54:44.285  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/gameactivity﹕ thread started
08-29 12:54:44.295  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/drawingstart﹕ screensize: Point(320, 480)
08-29 12:54:45.355  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ebe098
08-29 12:54:45.405  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ec5600
08-29 12:54:45.475  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ed3650
08-29 12:54:45.545  12655-12655/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@41ee6d00
08-29 12:55:06.505  12655-12658/hu.frontrider.space I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
08-29 12:55:06.565  12655-12658/hu.frontrider.space I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-29 12:58:02.335  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/gameactivity﹕ thread started
08-29 12:58:02.335  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/drawingstart﹕ screensize: Point(320, 480)
08-29 12:58:15.195  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@421541e8
08-29 12:58:15.245  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@4215d9a0
08-29 12:58:15.305  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@4216fed0
08-29 12:58:15.375  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@4218dd20
08-29 12:58:15.445  12774-12774/hu.frontrider.space I/ProjectileHandler﹕ Added: hu.frontrider.space.Entity.Projectiles.Projectile@421b4290
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not exit the application by calling :

```
System.exit(0);
```

You would better call

```
finish();

 public void ExitButonClick()
{

    exit_button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    finish();
                }

            }
    );
}
```

inside the onClickListener. finish() respects the lifecycle of the activity, whereas exit() does not.